# Returning a function with callback as input without inputting one at beginning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am currently reading some codebase but I meet some code I can't understand at all.

```
const asyncMapper = (name, done) => (payload, cb) => {
  post(name, {...payload}, (...params) => {
    if(isFunction(done))
      done(cb, ...params)
    else
      cb(...params)
  })
}
```

The asyncMapper function will accept a variable `name` and `done` which is (hopefully) a function as input. It will return another function with `payload` and a callback function `cb` as input.

While I understand payload may come from somewhere like the action/reducer, where can the callback function come from. There is no way to input one anyway. (so for the `...params`)

Comment: payload and cb are *arguments to the returned function*, so they're supplied by the caller. The gathered params array is from what is fed to the anonymous callback by post. What does this have to do with React anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reformat that code a little bit to make the separation of its components a little easier to understand.

```js
const asyncMapper = (name, done) => 
    (payload, cb) => {
        post(
            name,
            {...payload},
            (...params) => {
                if(isFunction(done))
                    done(cb, ...params);
                else
                    cb(...params);
            }
        )
    }
```

Essentially, passing in `name` and `done` values generate a function that uses those values. That generated function takes a `payload` and a `cb` (callback). It calls the `post` function (though I'm not sure where this comes from), passing in the `name`, the `payload` object with `{...payload}`, and ANOTHER generated function with no declared parameters. The use of `...params` means that whatever parameters passed into this function can be passed into any functions called in its scope.

This generated function uses the `isFunction` function (also not sure where this comes from) using the `done` function. If `isFunction(done)` returns true, it calls the `done` function, passing it the `cb` function and whatever parameters were sent to this generated function. If `isFunction(done)` returns false, it calls the `cb` function, passing in whatever params were sent to this generated function.

In use, assuming you've already defined `name`, `done`, `payload`, and `cb` values, it would look something like this:

```js
const generated = asyncMapper(name, done); // Generate the function

generated(payload, cb); // Call the generated function
```

The rest of the functionality depends on the `isFunction` and `post` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
const asyncMapper = (name, done) => (payload, cb) => {
  post(name, {...payload}, (...params) => {
    if(isFunction(done))
      done(cb, ...params)
    else
      cb(...params)
  })
}
```

Can be understood as below:

```
var asyncMapper = function asyncMapper(name, done) {
  return function (payload, cb) {
    post(name, { ...payload
    }, function () {
      for (var _len = arguments.length, params = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
        params[_key] = arguments[_key];
      }

      if (isFunction(done)) done.apply(void 0, [cb].concat(params));else cb.apply(void 0, params);
    });
  };
};
```